# Redirect all http/https requests to a proxy server

Tags: proxy, https, http

I have a host A that in network 1 with B C D, and A is also part of network 2 with internet. All the http/https requests from B C D are going to A, and access internet through network 2. I want to add a proxy server, does add all setting in A will work? Any suggestion?

Comment: I have read your question 3 times, and I am not quite sure that I can wrap my head around what you are actually asking. If you simply want a proxy server to proxy http/https requests, have a look at squid.

Comment: For `HTTP` you might look for Squid as _transparent proxy_. Of course it will not work for `HTTPS` without the clients' compliance.